# Can't get correct source from HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I'm trying to get the [this](http://www.soccer24.com/team/barcelona/SKbpVP5K/results/) page's source code with htmlunit, but it seems that some javascript is not being executed (or maybe something else is happening). It only returns the page as on the "Loading..." stage who is displayed before the tables appear. Am I doing something wrong?

My Code:

```
[...] WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
Page page = webClient.getPage(url);
WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
String content = response.getContentAsString();
System.out.println("HTML: " + content); [...]
```

Comment: I suspect the page has javascript to modify the content and it has not finished running when you grab the content. Try adding `webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(10000);` right after getting the page.

Comment: Already tried it, but just to be sure i tried it again... and nope, same page without the tables...

Comment: Does the page take more than 10 seconds to load? If so, change the timeout to a more appropriate value. Other than that, I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: Also tried 20, 30, 40 and 60...

Comment: Got it solved. Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

page.`getWebResponse()` returns the response as received from the server without JavaScript modifications.

You should use:

```
page.asXml()
```

or

```
page.asText()
```

For that page, HtmlUnit seems to through an error:

> Invalid JavaScript value of type com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException

Comment: So, there is no way of getting the page with the tables?

Comment: Got it! Just changed the browser version to "FIREFOX_52", and get the page as XML, as you suggested.
Thank you very much!